# How to complete an animation instantaneously if it has not finished?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have started an Animation in a method and later I will have to stop it and complete it immediately if it has not completed then.

```
Vector diff = ...
DoubleAnimation aniX = new DoubleAnimation(diff.X, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4));
DoubleAnimation aniY = new DoubleAnimation(diff.Y, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4));
```

`aniX` and `aniY` to be stopped, if they have not completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `XAML` code with some attached `Trigger` to stop it. To stop the animation programmatically. You can try using `Begin` to begin the `Storyboard` and `Stop` to stop it (don't use `BeginAnimation`):

```
Storyboard st = new Storyboard();
Storyboard.SetTarget(aniX, yourObject);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(aniX, yourPropertyPath);
st.Children.Add(aniX);
Storyboard.SetTarget(aniY, yourObject);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(aniY, yourPropertyPath);
st.Children.Add(aniY);
//begin
st.Begin();
//stop
st.Stop();
```

**NOTE**: The code above supposes you declare all the `DoubleAnimations` and `Storyboard` in procedural code (not in XAML code). I think you should declare them in `XAML` code to make it more concise, many class and stuff in `WPF` are optimized for `XAML`, so sometimes you can feel it's a little weird to look them in procedural code.